# How to send a "reminder" to a recruiter?

Tags: interviewing, internship, email

*If you don’t hear from me by mid-week (Wednesday or Thursday) will you do me a favor and drop me an email to give me a reminder so I can communicate with you on the summer internship.*

How would you phrase the response?

Comment: I don't think you need to over-think this: anything polite will do! e.g. "Hi - I'm still interested in the summer internship if you have more information for me now please? Thanks!"

Answer (score 1):

I'd say something along the lines of:

"Hey,

Just wanted to say hey and see where things are in regards to the internship we were speaking of?

Thanks,
"

So just keep it casual and nice, something like that.

Comment: To me "where things are" sounds a bit like you're chasing someone for a dependency they owe you, and it's their fault. Which is true I suppose, but doesn't feel quite right to me for a relationship with someone you want to recruit you. That said, chances are they'll ignore the content and just take the reminder anyway so I suppose it's moot.

Comment: @Rup I mean no offense, but sounds like you're being somewhat overly sensitive.  "where things are" puts the blame on no one.  It simply asks what is the state of the situation.

Comment: OK, but the situation is that you're waiting for them to get back to you, and you both know that, and you're being deliberately vague about it. So it feels slightly off to me, but then I can't imagine it'd actually put anyone's nose out-of-joint.

Comment: @Rup there's nothing vague about asking what is the state of the potential job.

Answer (score 0):

Simply present the context of your discussion and explain that you are sending this email because she/he asked you to do so. Then reaffirm your interest for the summer internship. Do not forget to add you availability in case she/he wants to contact you by phone.

It will perfectly do the job, while emphasizing your interest and motivation for this internship = perfect.

Sometimes, when recruiters ask for an email reminder it's simply to be sure the applicant is still motivated and interested in the position. Tricky I know ;-)

Comment: "Simply present the context of your discussion" - the easiest way to do that is just reply to the email you've been sent. If you do that I don't think you need to explain why you're sending the email either: it should be obvious.